# How to move all array elements up to global scope in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, scope, global-variables, global

I have a function in PHP which returns an array:

```
$Function_Returned_Array = array(

  ['Array_1'] => array('Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3'),
  ['Array_2'] => array('Element4', 'Element5', 'Element6'),
  ['Array_3'] => array('Element7', 'Element8', 'Element9')
);
```

But what I really need in the global scope is three separate arrays:

```
  $Array_1 = array('Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3');
  $Array_2 = array('Element4', 'Element5', 'Element6');
  $Array_3 = array('Element7', 'Element8', 'Element9');
```

This is so that in the Global Scope, I don't need to call:

```
$Function_Returned_Array['Array_1']
```

But I can call instead:

```
$Array_1
```

How can I move all the array elements up to global scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comment, PHP does have a function that will do exactly that:

```
$Function_Returned_Array = array(
  'Array_1' => array('Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3'),
  'Array_2' => array('Element4', 'Element5', 'Element6'),
  'Array_3' => array('Element7', 'Element8', 'Element9')
);

extract($Function_Returned_Array);
print_r($Array_1); //Works
```

However with lack of context I must point out that there are some notable caveats with this solution:

1. You risk overwriting other variables with the same name. PHP will not warn or otherwise notify you this is happening. For example, consider the following code:

```php
function saveData() {
     $isAuthenticated = $_SESSION['user'];
     extract($_POST);
     if (!$isAuthenticated) {
        return false;
     }
     // Save data
}
```

The problem here is if someone sends `isAuthenticated` as part of the request payload which will overwrite your own variable.

2. Most IDEs will not know about the existence of those variables which will result in losing any completion help and often getting warnings of undefined variables.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you, @apokryfos! I note in the PHP manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), there is a list of _Extraction Flags_ (EXTR_OVERWRITE, EXTR_SKIP, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL etc.) to give instructions about what to do when variable name collisions occur.

Comment: Perfect! `extract()` was exactly what I needed - thank you @apokryfos.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
foreach ($fnc_returned_arr as $key => $arr)
{
    ${$key} = $arr;
}

echo '<pre>'. print_r($Array_1, 1) .'</pre>';
```

So we just loop and use the array key as the var name for usage elsewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

After working on this for some time this is my own solution, using:

- `array_keys()`
- dynamic variables

Is there a better solution than this?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_keys($My_Array)); $i++) {

  ${array_keys($My_Array)[$i]} = $My_Array[array_keys($My_Array)[$i]];
}
```

Comment: I think you *have* to use dynamic variable declaration here.. unless you do something to your function that returns those arrays

Comment: Foreach is probably easier.

Comment: *After working on this for some time*. You mean the four minutes between when you posted the question and your answer?

Comment: Sure. I came up with the problem about an hour before I posted and I came up with my solution about 10mins before. I posted anyway, because I figured there were probably better solutions out there.